# Regular Expression Interval Quantifier

Tags: regex, rubular

Here is my Regular Expression:

```
(?i)(test){1,3}
```

Here are the strings I am using to test:

> test test test test

I am using rubular.com to test.

My interpretation of my Regular Expression is

> case insensitive, search for the word test without quotations a maximum of 3 times, but a minimum of 1.

On the line that outputs the results, my is the word "test" highlighted 4 times? Why doesn't it only highlight 3 times? I thought it would search 1 time minimum and 3 times maximum?

[image]

Comment: You simply have 4 matches of you regular expression. Match test 3 times (i.e. test{3,3} ) would match "testtesttest" but not "test test test"

Comment: Why doesn't it only highlight 3 times? I thought it would search 1 time minimum and 3 times maximum?

Comment: Try the test string "testtest testtesttesttest testtesttest"

Comment: Do you mean you want to limit the number of matches inside the regex pattern? It is not how regex is supposed to work. You may use programming means for it. Are you using Ruby? What is the real life scenario?

Comment: You have 4 matched test{1} [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) @LunchBox

Comment: What is the programming language? You cannot solve your problem with a pure regex.

Comment: Is it Ruby?....

Comment: I was just playing around with rubular.com. I was trying to teach myself some regex because I'm a junior etl developer.